# How to retrive ci management url in SonarQube?

Tags: configuration, continuous-integration, sonarqube, administration

Links section of my SonarQube configuration page is completely blank and no links are automatically populated here. Any help on how to populate default links on this page which are supposed to be retrieved from project pom?

Answer (score 1):

The CI management URL is automatically fed during SonarQube analysis:

- either using the value of the value of the `<url>` tag of the `<ciManagement>` section of the POM:

`<ciManagement>
  <system>Jenkins</system>
  <url>the_url_of_your_ci_system</url>
</ciManagement>`

- or more generally (if you're not using Maven) using the property `sonar.links.ci`